# SQL Oracle : How to get the sum result of GROUP BY , How to select data that not the same condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

This is my sql

```
SELECT userType , COUNT(*) total
FROM tableA
WHERE userType = 'N'
AND user_date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY userType 
UNION ALL
SELECT userType , COUNT(*) total
FROM tableA
WHERE userType = 'Y'
GROUP BY userType;
```

result is

```
___________ ________
| USERTYPE | TOTAL |
--------------------
| N        | 5     |
| Y        | 4     |
--------------------
```

My question is how to get the result to be like this.

```
___________ ________
| USERTYPE | TOTAL |
--------------------
| N        | 5     |
| Y        | 4     |
| SUM      | 9     |
--------------------
```

Or if it can't be what would it should be to sum all of the total value.
my sql on the top isn't fix if you have a better way you can change it
ever you think it works
, please tell me thank you.

Comment: 1) No need to UNION ALL. Just GROUP BY.

Comment: if i want to get userType = 'N' user_date should not NULL
but if i want userType = 'Y' userType just be Y user_date is whatever i can't get these thing together

Comment: `WHERE (userType = 'N' AND user_date IS NOT NULL) OR userType = 'Y'`

Comment: BTW, are you using MySQL or Oracle?

Comment: i'm using SQL oracle sorry for my taged mistake.

Comment: No problem, we are all here to learn.

Comment: thank you a lot it's working now !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One method is `grouping sets`.  But `union` is not needed for this query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(userType, 'SUM'), COUNT(*) as total
FROM tableA
WHERE (userType = 'N' AND user_date IS NOT NULL) OR
      userType = 'Y' 
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( (userType), () );
```

Comment: I got a problem with the userType =  'N' because user_date of it should not be null.But if userType = 'Y' user_date can be whatever.

Comment: Thank Bro ! i just changed WHERE to be 
WHERE (userType = 'N' AND user_date IS NOT NULL) OR userType = 'Y' 
so it's working !

Comment: @aofwerta . . . I thought that was a typo in the question.  I updated the answer.